# How do I make a Material toolbar opaque on scroll and transparent at start?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm currently trying to familiarise myself with angular. I'm using angular material and I'm looking to make the material toolbar sticky and opaque on scroll and, transparent with toolbar text still visible when at the very top of the page. Everything I've searched for so far involved javascript or jquery. How do I go about it in angular 8 precisely?

This is my HTML & CSS respectively:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <a mat-button [routerLink]="['home']" >
    <h1>PETER<span class="light">CONSTRUCTION</span></h1>
  </a>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <a mat-button [routerLink]="['home']" routerLinkActive="active" >HOME</a>
  <a mat-button [routerLink]="['about']" routerLinkActive="active">ABOUT</a>
  <a mat-button [routerLink]="['contact']" routerLinkActive="active">CONTACT</a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

---

```
  mat-toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: #c3cfd2;

}

mat-toolbar-row {
  justify-content:space-between;

}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

a.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}

h1 .light {
  font-weight: 100;

}

/*.x-bar.x-bar-absolute{*/
/*  background-color: hsla(276, 6%, 63%, 0.15) !important;*/
/*  transition: none !important;*/
/*}*/

/*.x-bar.x-bar-fixed{*/
/*  background-color: hsla(276, 6%, 63%, 1) !important;*/
/*}*/

/*.x-bar [class^="x-bg"] {*/
/*  background-color: transparent !important;*/
/*}*/

/*.x-bar.x-bar-absolute .hm5.x-menu > li > .x-anchor .x-anchor-text-primary {*/
/*  color: #fff;*/
/*}*/

/*.x-bar.x-bar-fixed .hm5.x-menu > li > .x-anchor .x-anchor-text-primary {*/
/*  color: #000;*/
/*}*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this, but since you're already using `@angular/material`, you can take advantage of the `@angular/cdk` and it's `ScrollDispatchModule` (see [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api)).

It allows you for easy and clean observing of scroll events for registered elements, outside of the NgZone, meaning it will have small impact on the performance.

See the example stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npdbtp

First, you need to import `ScrollDispatchModule` and register provider for `ScrollDispatcher`:

```
import {ScrollDispatchModule, ScrollDispatcher} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    (other imports)
    ScrollDispatchModule
  ],
  providers: [ScrollDispatcher]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in your template you can mark an html element with the `cdkScrollable` directive. This will automatically register it in the `ScrollDispatcher`.
You can also bind component's style (e.g. opacity) to a property defined in your component:

```
<div class="scroll-wrapper" cdkScrollable>
  <mat-toolbar class="sticky-toolbar" [style.opacity]="opacity">My App</mat-toolbar>
  <div>content</div>
</div>
```

You can make html element sticky using the `display: sticky` together with `top: 0`:

```
.sticky-toolbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Then you will need to inject the `ScrollDispatcher` and `NgZone` into your component and define opacity property:

```
  opacity = 1;
  constructor(
    private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher,
    private zone: NgZone
  ) {}
```

Then you can subscribe to scrolled events of the ScrollDispatcher. Those are emitted for all the registered components. You can also register to scroll events of a single element - refer to the docs if needed by.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((event: CdkScrollable) => {
      const scroll = event.measureScrollOffset("top");
      let newOpacity = this.opacity;

      if (scroll > 0) {
        newOpacity = 0.75;
      } else {
        newOpacity = 1;
      }

      if (newOpacity !== this.opacity) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.opacity = newOpacity;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The `ScrollDispatcher` runs outside of NgZone, meaning it will not run change detection in the whole application. This allows for better performance, and it's why we're also injecting NgZone and running the property change inside the zone - this calls the proper change detection along the tree of components.

Comment: Hi thank you, I gave this a shot  and added the respective modifications but it still doesn't work. The other thing i noticed from the stackblitz is you've set it up to function the other way round (transparent on scroll and opaque at the start) I switched it however but, how do I make it so that when it's completely translucent the header writings are still visible in black.

Comment: Not sure what "still doesn't work" mean.

Instead of changing opacity of whole header, you can apply styles using `[ngStyle]` or classes using `[ngClass]` - I've updated the stackblitz linked above (clicked save instead of fork - my bad) to make it transparent when on top and "filled" when scrolled at least 1px from top.

Comment: Thanks, your update was perfect. As for clarity on "still doesn't work" when I scroll down on my webpage the toolbar still remains the same as it was before a scroll. There is no change in opacity. Is there anything in the CSS I uploaded that might interfere with the modifications you've suggested?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code first-hand. Try inspecting the html element and see if 1. The styles / classes from my solution are properly applied, and 2. They are not overwritten by anything.
PS - If you think this answer is correct, please mark it as such so that others don't find your question when they look for unanswered questions :)

Comment: Okay, i'll check that but before i do, I'm working with webstorm and it does not recognise `import {ScrollDispatchModule, ScrollDispatcher} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';` it only recognises `import {ScrollDispatcher, ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
` I'm wondering does that make a difference and if so whats the fix for it because I do have  `@angular/cdk` installed I believe.

Comment: It seems ScrollDispatchModule has been renamed to ScrollingModule as of 8.0.0. Old alias is still working, but is marked as deprecated - perhaps that's why your IDE is unhappy about it. On stackblitz, using 8.2.9 both are working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209454/discussion-between-blank-and-totallynewb).

Comment: @TotallyNewb thank you for your solution...however my scroll value is always defined. Checked the code on stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-drhmwf?file=src%2Fstyles.css and I am doing the same thing there really...could have an idea why I am getting `undefined`?

Comment: Again thank you! I figured it out... it's important to specify 
`.scroll-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100vh;
  }`
Once I added this it worked as expected. Thanks!