# How to listen scroll in angular and add/remove class based on the scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

I am new to Angular, working on a project where the second div should start scrolling one the first div reaches its bottom. I have manage to do it using Vanilla Javascript but not sure how I can achieve the same in Angular. Any help would be appreciated. [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/8wgr1fb3/)

**Styles**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.container.nopadding {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: #474752;
  position: fixed;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container-2.auto {
  position: static;
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="overflow">
<div class="container">
  Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum
  ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum
  sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus.
  Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque
  in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum
  ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum
  ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum
  sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus.
</div>
<div class="container-2">
  <h1>
    Container 2 title
  </h1>
  Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur aliquet quam id
  dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.
</div>
```

**Script**

```
(function() {
  let container = document.querySelector('.container');
  let containerScroll = document.querySelector('.container-2');
  let containersHeight = container.offsetHeight;

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log("Into scroll");
    if (Math.floor(window.scrollY) >= Math.floor(container.offsetTop + containersHeight - window.innerHeight)) {
      containerScroll.classList.add('auto');
      container.classList.add('nopadding');
    }
    else {
      containerScroll.classList.remove('auto');
      container.classList.remove('nopadding');
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a Material toolbar opaque on scroll and transparent at start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60627947/how-do-i-make-a-material-toolbar-opaque-on-scroll-and-transparent-at-start)

Comment: The linked answer covers the scrolling and reading scroll position. Simply replace manipulating opacity with changing a variable that is passed to the `[ngClass]` directive in the required place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it can ben done in angular (just translating your code to the Angular way):

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-doing-js-stuff-in-angular?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("firstContainer") containerOne: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("secondContainer") containerTwo: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostListener("window:scroll")
  adjustHeights() {
    console.log("Into scroll");
    const containersHeight = this.containerOne.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    if (
      Math.floor(window.scrollY) >=
      Math.floor(
        this.containerOne.nativeElement.offsetTop +
          containersHeight -
          window.innerHeight
      )
    ) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.containerTwo.nativeElement, "auto");
      this.renderer.addClass(this.containerOne.nativeElement, "nopadding");
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.containerTwo.nativeElement, "auto");
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.containerOne.nativeElement, "nopadding");
    }
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="overflow">
<div class="container" #firstContainer>
  Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum
  ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum
  sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus.
  Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque
  in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum
  ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum
  ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum
  sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus.
</div>
<div class="container-2" #secondContainer>
  <h1>
    Container 2 title
  </h1>
  Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur aliquet quam id
  dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.
</div>
```

css is the same.

I think it would be better to do this using CSS (probably some playing around with `position: sticky`), but I really haven't thought about it in depth, its just my instinct

Comment: I tried the position sticky way but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Any hint? @Moshezauros

Comment: sorry, I dont have it in my head without doing some leg work, like I said, the sticky path might not be valid, just my instinct